# Rails 4 + audited: Get audits for deleted object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audit

I am using the [Audited Gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) with my project but I don't understand how to get the audit trail for a deleted object.  Their example shows:

```
user = User.create!(name: "Steve")
user.audits.count # => 1
user.update_attributes!(name: "Ryan")
user.audits.count # => 2
user.destroy
user.audits.count # => 3
```

but if all I know is that a user is missing, how can I access the `audit` since I need access to the object that gets audited?

Comment: I haven't used `audited` but if you know the `id` of deleted records, you could do `User.new(id: deleted_id)` and  call audits on that object... alternatively you could examine the `audited` table itself... it shouldn't be hard to determine where `id` is stored and be able to identify `destroy` audit records.

Comment: can you show me what you get in `user.audits`?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I can't seem to examine any audit table through the terminal, but I can through looking through my database with something like PSequel.

Comment: @uzaif I don't think you get the issue.  I don't have a `user` object to call `audits` on if the object was deleted days ago.  All I know is that its missing and I cannot query `Audit` for audits with a given type.

Comment: If there was a migration that created the audit table and if there's a table you can see through direct inspection of the database, you should be able to create your own Model to access it... `class AuditTable < ApplicationRecord; self.table_name = "(whatever table name you see in the schema or in the inspection)"; end`  You can then delete a user and see what the deleted audit record looks like, and then you have an idea of how to search for deleted records in the audit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the id of the user, you can try:

```
Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit.where(auditable_type: 'User', auditable_id: user_id)
```

For specific actions like create, update, destroy, you can try their scopes - creates, updates, destroys. I found it [on their github repo](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/master/lib/audited/audit.rb).

Answer (score 0):

For version 4.7.1, it can be done like so:

```
Audited::Audit.where(auditable_type: 'User', auditable_id: user_id)
```

The ActiveRecord model is a class within the Audited module.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/v4.7.1/lib/audited/audit.rb#L36